# Declaring RequireJS dependencies with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, frontend

I am using TypeScript with RequireJS. As you can see in the following image, I define some imports using the RequireJS config; of course these imports are sourced via `<script>` tags:

[image]

TypeScript cannot see those declarations, so I was thinking of just declaring them as globals or something, to avoid transpilation errors.
What might be the best thing to do in this situation? Everything seems to run fine, but I do get more compilation errors and of course red syntax highlighting everywhere.

In the first image we see that `requirejs` is not recognized, also in the below image we see that TypeScript doesn't know what `'redux'` is, (but it's in the RequireJS config).

[image]

So what I would like to do is tell TypeScript about the following dependencies: requirejs, redux, react, rxjs, socketio, etc

Comment: as an aside, besides the problem mentioned in the question, RequireJS seems to work pretty well with TS; TS will just wrap your code with AMD syntax when you transpile and then RequireJS will load your files individually (in development mode).

Comment: Have you tried `npm install --save-dev @types/redux`? (and likewise with the rest of your dependencies?)

Comment: yeah I have for most of my deps...but I think TS is expecting redux to be an npm install and it's not :) do you follow ?

Comment: I have to somehow tell TypeScript that my redux dep is being sourced by RequireJS and that it's indeed present...

Comment: I edited the question title to be clearer

Comment: well it turns out, simply installing the @types, got rid of the syntax highlighting being red, but not sure if the compilation/transpilation errors will still be there

Comment: When you do `npm install --save-dev @types/redux`, you're not installing the dependency. You're installing the corresponding types for that dependency. You normally have to do that separately anyways.

Comment: right, I get that part

Comment: I'm not sure what else you need then! You have your js library from require and your types from npm install. You should be good to go.

Comment: right, but TypeScript has no right to know where the redux dep is coming from, unless TS is really looking in the requirejs.config({}) object, which I doubt

Comment: Why does it need to know *where* it's coming from? It has it thanks to requirejs and it knows what it looks like thanks to the definitions. What more does TS need to know?

Comment: I would be surprised if the code transpiles without errors - even though you have the type definitions if you don't have the source usually compilers will complain, but I haven't looked at the compile output yet. I have the source via RequireJS, but (a) I don't know if TS can read the RequireJS config and (b) they are network deps and don't get loaded until runtime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So part of the problem was I needed to run:

```
npm install -D @types/requirejs
npm install -D @types/redux
```

and then in my `tsconfig.json`, add:

```
  "types": [
      "node",
      "lodash",
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "redux",
      "react-redux",
      "async",
      "requirejs"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
```

but also, to address the problem of TypeScript not understand where `<script>` tag dependencies come from in the front-end, it looks like we can do something like this:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/12/External-JavaScript-dependencies-in-Typescript-and-Angular-2

> De-referencing Globals In order to keep the Typescript compiler happy
>   and not end up with compilation errors, or have a boat load of type
>   imports you may only use once or twice, it's sometimes easier to
>   simply manage the external libraries yourself. Import it using a
>   regular script tag, or packaged as part of a separate vendor bundle
>   and then simply referenced in the main page.
>
> So rather than using import to pull in the library, we can just import
>   using  tag as in the past:
>
> Then in any Typescript class/component where you want to use these
>   libraries explicitly dereference each of the library globals by
>   explicitly using declare and casting them to any:

```
declare var redux:any; 
declare var socketio: any;
```